# PyQt5, MacOS - Force GUI to stick with currently opened desktop space

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am developing a small GUI application that can be shown/hidden using a tray icon in the MacOS menubar using PyQt5.

Unfortunately there is a small problem where I can not find a solution for.

Scenario: I run my python script in a terminal window to start the application*. The icon appears and I can show/hide the GUI just fine using the menu tray icon. However, if I switch to another desktop space and subsequently click the menu tray icon to open the GUI, MacOS switches back to the desktop space I opened the application on.

What I would like to achieve: show the GUI on whatever desktop space is currently opened.

Does anyone have experience with such an implementation?

Thanks for reading.

- NB: when the application is done I plan to convert it to .app, however this is of course not ideal for the developing process.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are seeing this thread anywhere in the future, I eventually figured it out :-)

Adding the window flag `QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` to my main GUI class makes sure the GUI is always opened on the desktop space that is currently present.

```
self.setWindowFlags(
    QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
)
```